# How do I avoid re-rendering a connected React PureComponent due to mapDispatchToProps functions?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

whenever mapDispatchToProps is called, it generates new functions to return. For example:

```
const mapDispatchToProps = function(dispatch, ownProps) {
  return {
    addToStack: (episodeId, stackId) => {
      return dispatch(StackAction.addEpisodeToStack(episodeId, stackId));
    },
  };
}
```

Every time the mapDispatchToProps is called, it will generate a new object, with a new arrow function.

In my application I often have to avoid re-rendering my components. Using a PureComponent is often the way to go. However, since the functions are always different, PureComponent won't help and I'd have to create a shouldComponentUpdate strategy. There, I'd have to "blacklist" all of the mapDispatchToProps functions and ignore all of them. I'd have to add every new function to the list so it'd avoid re-rendering.

here is an example of the blacklist shouldComponentUpdate boilerplate:

```
const blacklist = [
  'addToStack',
]

shouldComponentUpdate(nextProps, nextState) {
  for (let i in nextProps) {
    if (blacklist.includes(i)) continue;
    if (nextProps[i] !== this.props[i]) {
      return true;
    }
  }
  for (let i in nextState) {
    if (nextState[i] !== this.state[i]) {
      return true;
    }
  }
  return false;
}
```

I've come up with a new solution

```
const dispatch;
const mapDispatchToPropsFunctions = {
  addToStack: (episodeId, stackId) => {
    return dispatch(StackAction.addEpisodeToStack(episodeId, stackId));
  },
};

const mapDispatchToProps = function(dispatchArg, ownProps) {
  dispatch = dispatchArg
  return mapDispatchToPropsFunctions;
}
```

this way the functions are constant and won't trigger a re-rendering of a PureComponent and I don't have to maintain a shouldComponentUpdate function.

however this seems wrong to me.
Is there a "default" way of dealing with this problem?

Comment: According to the React docs: "An update can be caused by changes to props or state."  What makes you think a re-render is occurring on mapDispatchToProps?  Further, why are you dispatching an action if you aren't looking for a state change?

Comment: @jmargolisvt In my example, whenever mapDispatchToProps is called, the addToStack props will be a different function.

Comment: @jmargolisvt so the re-render is not occurring on mapDispatchToProps but rather in consequence of mapDispatchToProps being called. Dispatching an action surely could cause an update, but I'm not talking about dispatching actions here. Re-renders will occur regardless of dispatching actions

Comment: I've adapted the wording in the question, maybe it'll be clearer now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I generally advise to *not* try to recreate functions that capture props values like that, but instead have a handler method on your class that passes prop values to the action creator.  I also advise that people not write `mapDispatch` functions directly, but use the "object shorthand" for `connect()`.

Example:

```
const actions = {addToStack : StackAction.addEpisodeToStack};

class MyComponent extends React.Component {
    addToStack = () => {
        this.props.addToStack(this.props.episodeId, this.props.stackId);
    }
}
```

In your specific snippet, it looks like you're not even referencing any props values in `mapDispatch` anyway, so there was no need to declare the `ownProps` parameter.  (`connect` will only call a `mapDispatch` function multiple times if the `ownProps` parameter is requested.  Otherwise, it only calls `mapDispatch` once, when the component is created.)

Comment: "if the ownProps parameter is requested"
@markerikson how do you detect that ? do you read the arguments.length of the mapdispatchtoprops or do you attach proxies to the ownprops to detect if read has happened, or do you pass changed prop values to the component and see if the result of the mapstatetoprops has changed ?

Comment: EDIT: ok I see from https://github.com/reduxjs/react-redux/blob/0c048f0646754de103cc2d9825762340bed06119/src/connect/wrapMapToProps.js#L22 , that you are reading the argument object length. So I have two questions

1) why is this approach chosen, as opposed to other methods that I have mentioned in previous comment
2) Isn't it much safer to pass some EXPLICIT option, for example to connect, that the mapstatetodispatch function is going to or not going to read the ownprops . for example

connect(mapstatetoprops, mapdispatchtoprops, null, null, { readingFromOwnProps:  true })

Comment: Because this was implemented in the earliest versions of React-Redux in 2015, and we can't assume that `Proxy` exists in the runtime environment even today. Also, passing an additional option like that just to configure use of `mapState` is an extremely ugly API design.

Comment: ok its ugly, maybe can be improved,  but if they have written their function as
mapstatetoprops(..args) and now they are not using the ownprops, this will cause unneccessary calling of mapstatetoprops correct even though they are not using ownprops

Comment: hi mark, just in case you missed my comment , can you reply on this (apologise in advance if I am spamming you)
"ok its ugly, maybe can be improved, but if they have written their function as mapstatetoprops(..args) and now they are not using the ownprops, this will cause unneccessary calling of mapstatetoprops correct even though they are not using ownprops"

Comment: No one's ever going to write their `mapState` that way, and in the 5+ years since React-Redux came out, I can't remember anyone ever raising a concern about that.

Comment: Oh alright cool. On an related note, I had access to GPT-3 AI, so what is your opinion of Gpt3 powered eslint, which rules can it enhance, also let me know if you want go run something  on it or are curious about, will share with you

Answer (score 0):

Turns out that the actual solution is to not use `mapDispatchToProps` at all.
In the [react-redux docs](https://react-redux.js.org/api/connect#object-shorthand-form) there is a reference to a shorthand method:

> If an object is passed, each function inside it is assumed to be a
>   Redux action creator. An object with the same function names, but with
>   every action creator wrapped into a dispatch call so they may be
>   invoked directly, will be merged into the component’s props.

So the solution is to, instead of providing a function that binds dispatch to your action creators, just provide to connect an object containing your action creators as second argument. Connect will only bind them once and use the same functions all the time, avoiding unnecessary re-renders.

This should be in fact the preferred way of supplying action creators to connect.

Comment: Note that [the "object shorthand" is highlighted and recommended in the `mapDispatch` usage guide](https://react-redux.js.org/using-react-redux/connect-mapdispatch#defining-mapdispatchtoprops-as-an-object), and [our new Style Guide docs page specifically recommends using it as well](https://redux.js.org/style-guide/style-guide#use-the-object-shorthand-form-of-mapdispatch-with-connect).

Comment: great! that will make things more transparent and usually better